# Is Holo theme included in all 4.0 devices?

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm using `android:Theme.Holo` in my activity and I'm wondering if there's any way this can be not recommended. I mean if it's possible that Holo theme is not present in the device (obviously in >=Honeycomb).
In case it's not present, I guess the app would just crash, wouldn't it?

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holo theme is mandatory on all Android 4.0 devices that are running Android Market.

Comment: I knew it was mandatory for devices running Play Store but I'm more concerned about custom ROMs... What about them? Is it possible that some ROMs don't include Holo?¿

Comment: Yes that is possible, but as theme is highly recommended for a full compatibility with apps it is rather unlikely. You really don't need to bother.

Answer (score 0):

Yes *Android 4.0* showcases the Holo theme family, further refined since its debut in *Android 3.0*. Indeed, *Google* continues its approach to unify the user experience on various Android devices by imposing native Holo theme (and its variations: Holo Holo Light and Light DarkActionBar) to access the Marketplace. So to ask your question all devices that run Android 4.0 uses the Holo theme.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers say, Holo is mandatory in 4.0, but if you want to support Holo on pre-4.0 phones then check out HoloEverywhere, https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was not looking for this approach but seeing that it's already done and usable I may reconsider it..